# How can I get mandatory whitespace in a specific rule while having other whitespace ignored?

Tags: parsing, whitespace, antlr, antlr4, grammar

The relevant part of my grammar is structured like this:

```cs
someRule: subrule1 | WS sign=('+' | '-') subrule2 ; // whitespace required here
// ... etc
WS: [ \t\r\n]+ -> channel(HIDDEN) ; // whitespace is usually ignored
```

I want to ignore whitespace, but require it on a specific rule. I'm pretty sure there was a way to do it in a previous ANTLR version (though I don't remember exactly, I think there was a syntax allowing to not hide them on a specific rule). I don't know how to do it in ANTLR4, of if it can be done at all without using language-specific actions.

I thought about making WS a parser rule somehow, but I don't think that's the right approach...
(and obviously I don't want to put WS? everywhere in the grammar)

Is there a (preferably language-independent) way to either (a) ensure that a specific point has whitespace, or (b) ensure both ends on a specific point are not "touching" on that channel, or (c) selectively choose the WS channel (default or hidden) depending on which rule it appears in somehow?
I'm guessing (c) is impossible and (a|b) would require language-dependent actions, unless I'm missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe there is any way to have parser rules evaluate tokens on the `HIDDEN` channel (or any channel other than 0).  Maybe I'm missing something but i couldn't find it.

The question I can't answer from your excerpts is whether there is another parser rule that should match if there is NOT a WS before your sign.  That makes a big difference.

I tend to think of a successful grammar as one that will produce a parse tree that represents the correct way to interpret the input stream.  IMHO, too many people complicate grammars by trying to encode "all the rules" into the grammar.  If you have an accurate tree of the only way to interpret the input (whether it's "error free" or not), then you can write a Listener (maybe a visitor) that visits the tree and performs edits for additional rules (such as "the 'sign' much be preceded by whitespace).

This accomplishes a couple of things:

- keeps the grammar simpler
- allows you to be very specific in your error messages.

ANTLR is pretty good about error messages, for what information it has, but "expected WS, but saw '+'", is just not going to be as good an error message as "signs must follow whitespace".

With that in mind, you can get to the HIDDEN channel inside a listener.

First of all you'll need to make the token Stream available in your Listener:

```java
class TestListener extends TestBaseListener {
    BufferedTokenStream tokens;

    public TestListener(BufferedTokenStream tokens) {
        this.tokens = tokens;
    }
    // ...
}
```

and pass it to the constructor of your listener:

```java
  CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
  TestListener listener = new TestListener(tokens);
```

then, in the `enter*` method for whatever rule you need to add this to, you can do something like the following:

```java
    const int HIDDEN = 1;

    @Override
    public void enterAddSub(TxlParser.AddSubContext ctx) {
        Token op = ctx.op;
        int opIndex = op.getTokenIndex();
        List<Token> hiddenChannel = tokens.getHiddenTokensToLeft(opIndex, HIDDEN);
        if (hiddenChannel != null) {
            Token ws = hiddenChannel.get(0);
            if (ws != null) {
                System.out.println("Found Ws (" + ws.getText() + ")");
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("There was no WS to the left of the operator");
            // Your code here to add an error 
        }
    }
```

for reference, this was the rule for I used with `AddSub`

```
expr:
    expr (MULT | DIV) expr                          # MulDiv
    | lExpr = expr op = (PLUS | MINUS) rExpr = expr # AddSub
    // ...
    ;
```

If I run this with input `a=x+y` I get:

```
There was no WS to the left of the operator
```

But the input `a=x +y` gives me:

```
Found Ws ( )
```